# ReactiveCocoa: how to keep signal until the server is connected?

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I have two signals (`RACSignal`):

1. `synchronizeToServerSignal`: a signal containing data to be sent to server.
2. `serverConnectionSignal`: a signal containing a boolean value to indicate the connection state.

The `synchronizeToServerSignal` will be triggered when a content is changed, and this signal is controlled by `serverConnectionSignal`:

- If the latest value of `serverConnectionSignal` is `YES`, `synchronizeToServerSignal` will keep sending the next value (`data`).
- If the latest value of `serverConnectionSignal` is `NO`, `synchronizeToServerSignal` will keep holding the latest value and discarding the old values. Once `serverConnectionSignal` sends `YES`, `serverConnectionSignal` will keep sending the next value again.

How to use **ReactiveCocoa** to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replayLast` will give you a signal that holds onto the latest value sent and discards old values. Then `if:then:else:` allows you to switch between two signals based on the value of a third boolean signal.

But what to switch between? Since you just want to ignore values, you can just use `[RACSignal empty]` -- thus switching between a signal with a useful value and a signal with *no* values:

```
[RACSignal if:serverConnectionSignal
         then:[synchronizeToServerSignal replayLast]
         else:[RACSignal empty]] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
   // sync here
}];
```

The *intent* of this code would be made a lot more clear by a helper method in a category, though:

```
@implementation RACSignal (Helpers)

- (RACSignal *)guard:(RACSignal *)boolSignal {
    return [RACSignal if:boolSignal then:self else:[RACSignal empty]];
}

@end
```

Then you can just write:

```
[[synchronizeToServerSignal replayLast] guard:serverConnectionSignal]
```

Much more clear!